# .NET Remoting List All Server Activated Objects

Tags: c#, remoting, .net-remoting, genuinechannels

I have a feeling that our .NET remoting services are getting overrun by objects instances that are hanging around on our server.

I cannot change code the to add additional logging right now, as this is a deployed production instance. We do, however have a code console built into the application that will let us execute any code in the server's app domain.

So, I'm looking for a way of getting a list (or a count) of all remoting activated (MarshalByRef) objects that currently exist for our open remoting channels. Also useful would be a list/count of all open client remoting Tcp channels to our server.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few .NET CLR Remoting performance counters that might be helpful:

.NET CLR Remoting

- Channels
- Context Proxies
- Context-Bound Classes Loaded
- Context-Bound Objects Alloc / sec
- Contexts
- Remote Calls/sec
- Total Remote Calls

Honestly not sure if any would help your particular case, but something to look into...

You can just use perfmon.exe to view them, but if you want to do it from C#, it is fairly easy as well.